# Query syntax instead loop with list<Process> difficult with translation

Tags: c#, list, loops, syntax

i hope i did't make any clone.
I am studying book effective c# wrote by Bill Wagner and stuck with using query syntax.

In my project i use something like that:

```
this.processList = new List<Process>();

            foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses(machine))
            {
                if (process.MainWindowTitle.Contains(patternTitle))
                {
                    this.processList.Add(process);
                }
            }

            if (processList.Count == 1)
            {
                this.handler = this.processList[0].MainWindowHandle;
            }
```

And i would like to use query syntax but i really don't have any idea how to.
I tried this under, but it fails. I know it won't work, but this is my proof that i tried.

> (from n in Enumerable.Range(0,
>   Process.GetProcesses(machine)).Contains select
>   var).add(value));

Any help will be appreciate.

 P.S. please correct my topic if it was not good specified. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to use LINQ be sure to include a "using System.LINQ;"

The LINQ expression you probably want is something like this:

```
var processList = from p in Process.GetProcesses(machine)
 where p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(patternTitle)
 select p;
```

There's lots of examples for LINQ around.  I use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linq as a reference.